# Inserting GIF in a button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, gif

i want to insert a gif in my button but when I do, it displays as a picture only (not animating). Is there any other way aside from using a picturebox (which plays gif).? thanks!

Comment: Nope. It only works on `PictureBoxes`.

Comment: what about modify PictureBox layout and use it as a button?

Comment: Or you could create a custom button that will animate the gif by overriding the OnPaint method and using the `ImageAnimator` class

Comment: how is that sir? @ZoharPeled sorry. am not that good in vb